# How do I discover SDA and SCL from I2C Address?

Tags: arduino, i2c

I'm using [Adafruit TCA9548A I2C Multiplexer](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tca9548a-1-to-8-i2c-multiplexer-breakout/overview), and I'm using `SoftI2CMaster.h` and this class uses SDA and SCL ports and pins.

I know the address from I2C Multiplexer, but I was wondering how to define SDA and SCL from this address.

Am I able to know SDA and SCL from I2C address?

Comment: SDA SCL are pins through which you connect I2C master and slave. What ae you trying to do ? What controller or board are you using?

Comment: @Nikhil I have an Arduino Mega, and I'm using the Adafruit Multiplexer to add 2 modules (heart sensors). This modules uses SDA and SCL each one.
When I put a code to read the Multiplexer, the answer is an address where the SDA and SCL are connected. But the code SoftI2CMaster, ask about SCL Port, SCL Pin and SDA Port and SDA Pin. I was just wondering which values I should put on this class to get the result.

Comment: Hi Marcio I am sorry for late reply! your question is unclear Can you post the code which you are referring to. From datasheet of mux you just need to tell the location of slave to mux to communicate to a specific slave!